# javascript: extracting text from html

Tags: javascript

I am getting html content as below:

```
var test='<div id="test">Raj</div>';
```

How can i retrieve value Raj from above html content using javascript.

Comment: say what? what do u want to do?

Comment: It seems like you already have Raj inside of a variable? I think more information might be needed here.

Comment: No, Raj just need to learn to use the {} button

Comment: @Raj, I think you have some quote problems too. Do you mean `var test='<div id="test">Raj</div>'; ???
`

Comment: @Neal, @Rionmonster, raj had the code in the editor, but didn't check that the output was going to come out correctly.

Comment: Sigh. Again someone is voting this down and voting to close just because it is not up to Strunk and White - be nice to non-native English speaking people, people!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to extract the text `"Raj"` from that HTML snippet?

To get the browser's HTML parser to do your dirty work for you:

```
// create an empty div
var div = document.createElement("div");

// fill it with your HTML
div.innerHTML = test;

// find the element whose text you want
test = div.getElementById("test");

// extract the text (innerText for IE, textContent for everyone else)
test = test.innerText || test.textContent;
```

Or in jQuery:

```
test = $(test).text();
```

Comment: that jQuery can be vastly refined. `$(test).find("#test").text();` for starters, no?

Comment: @mplungjan — You're right; I was sticking to too literal a translation of the non-jQuery version.  :-)

Comment: And with a selector rather than find?

Comment: okeee, that was very minimalistic ;) A bit like x.innerText where x is a whole lotta html with only one textnode ;)

Comment: @mplungjan — Yeah, I was originally thinking about situations like `<div id="foo">Foo</div><div id="bar">Bar</div>` and needing to get each bit of text separately, but that's rather more complicated than what the OP is asking for, even if I'm right about what he's trying to do.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery (I cannot believe I just said that ;)) you can get at the content immediately you wrap it in $(test).html

Someone else will tell you how to get at the innerHTML using a selector since everybody here are jQuery gurus but me

Update: somebody just did while I was editing: [javascript: extracting text from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398201/javascript-escape-html/5398271#5398271) - see comments or updates to that

Comment: How to escape all html content using javascript

Comment: @Raj What do you mean by "escape" ?

Answer (score -2):

```
var test = getElementById('test')
```

try that